# Web API alternative for RetrieveSharedPrincipalsAndAccessRequest

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am looking for a way to retrieve sharing permissions on specific entities.

Is there a way to do this via the web api?

I am aware of `RetrieveSharedPrincipalsAndAccessRequest` but since the rest of my tool relies only on the web api i would like to avoid using Organization Service completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This request is available in version 9.0 (Dynamics 365 july update)

I believe that your are using 8.x version. In such case this is not that simple but also doable. Simply create a custom Action:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481600.aspx

Actions can be used from workflows, plugins and, what is most useful in this scenario, directly called from WebAPI:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607600.aspx

So for example your call would look like that:

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/new_RetrievePrincipalAccessAction HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0

{
 "ObjectId": 3,
 "ObjectType": "account"
}
```

Now, you need to create a plugin and register it in Post-Operation of your action (actions generate a custom message that you can use to register plugins). For example:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/archive/2017/09/18/how-to-trigger-plugins-on-custom-messages-using-actions-in-dynamics-365

In your plugin, you can of course call the RetrieveSharedPrincipalsAndAccessRequest using standard IOrganizationService and simply put the result in OutputParameters of an action. Most useful would be JSON string:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    //do the logic retrieve what you want

    context.OutputParameters["result"] = someResultAsJsonString;
}
```

Your JS webAPI call will return

```
{
    result: someResultAsJsonString
}
```

And you can do whatever you want with this in your JS code :)

Comment: thanks, i am indeed using the 8.x api. your proposal seems a bit too much work when i can just use the assemblies and do the RetrieveSharedPrincipalsAndAccessRequest from my code. i just wanted to make sure i wasnt missing anything obvious

Comment: Yes but in that case you would be relying completely on WebAPI which was the requirement here as I presumed (for example if you cannot use CRM SDK, because you are using .NET Core or something). I guess this can be some work if you never done that, I am currently doing most of the logic inside CRM Actions with plugins under the hood (mostly because it's so simple to run this logic from almost anywhere in D365, so I can reuse it easily) so such operation for me would be a matter of 15 minutes tops.

Comment: well we have different perspectives, this is my first (and most likely) last time i have to work with dynamics in general so creating a plugin and things like that are a bit out of scope for me. Might give some inside to other readers though.